# I before E program not working

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, python-3.x, input

Just wrote a python program to determine how useful the mnemonic "I before E except after C" is.

With the input:

```
'I before e except when conducting an efficient heist on eight foreign neighbors. I believe my friend has left the receipt for the diet books hidden in the ceiling'
```

It would display:

```
Number of times the rule helped: 5
Number of times the rule was broken: 5
```

Changed a few things and thought I changed them back but the code is now broken, any advice will be helpful

```
while True:

    line = input("Line: ")                         
    count = 0                                       
    h = 0
    nh = 0


    words = line.split()                            
    for x in range(0, len(words)):                  
        word = words[count]

        if "ie" in word:                            
            if "cie" in word:                     
                nh += 1
            else:
                h +=1

        if "ei" in word:
            if "cei" in word:
                h += 1
            else:
                nh += 1
        else:
            h += 0
    count += 1                                      

    print("Number of times the rule helped:",h)     
    print("Number of times the rule was broken:",nh)
    print()
```

Comment: maybe x should be doing the indexing, not count?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. We're not here to pour over your entire program and guess what the problem might be. Please give specific information on why the code is "broken". Is there a test case that's not working out? If so, give us all the details about it.

Comment: Sorry for not giving enough info, I'm still pretty new here. What's happening is the input I posted earlier has no times the rule helped or was broken, no response from the program in the sense of returning an answer.

However, it still detects rule breakages/following in smaller inputs. I'm not sure why or how but I think I've broken the for loop or logic somehow

Comment: @musical_coder: "pore".

Comment: Don't forget weird words like "ancient" :)

Comment: @TomZych: nice catch...according to http://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/pore_pour_poor.htm, it should indeed be "pore". So much for acing the SAT test :)

Answer (score 1):

Good god I'm an idiot. I've probably spent a total of 3 hours or so trying to fix this thing.

```
for x in range(0, len(words)):                  
    word = words[count]

    if "ie" in word:                            
        if "cie" in word:                       
            nh += 1
        else:
            h +=1

    if "ei" in word:
        if "cei" in word:
            h += 1
        else:
            nh += 1
    count += 1
```

Can anyone spot the difference between this and the corresponding part of the old code? That 'count+=1' at the end is just indented an additional time. All those hours wasted... sorry if I wasted anyone else's time here :|

Comment: Hehe, welcome to our world :) Seriously, good job sticking at it- a lot of people just give up when in similar coding straights. That being said, I don't think you even need `count`- just use `word = words[x]`.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be well-served to better articulate your test cases.  I don't exactly understand what you're trying to do.

It seems like all you need is to see how many times 'cie' or 'cei' occurred in the text.

In which case:

```
for i in range(0, len(line)):

    print("scanning {0}".format(line[i:i+3]))
    if line[i:i+3].lower() == "cie":
        nh += 1
    if line[i:i+3].lower() == "cei":
        h += 1
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work. Good idea though, it seems like it should have worked. I'll take a look at it

Comment: I'm sorry, but comments like "this doesn't seem to work" are useless.  You're not going to find much help on stackoverflow unless you can give very explicit error feedback and so on.  Good luck with your debugging effort.